# second click on element if first click is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span:

```
<span class='click1 click2'>Click me </span>
```

You can see there are two classes **click1** and **click2**.

Now below is the script:

```
$(".click1").click(function () {
    alert('yes I am click1');
});
$(".click2").click(function () {
    if(confirm('Sure to Click1'))
        return false;
});
```

What I expect is to click2 will only be called if click1 allows.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
$(".click1").click(function() {
  alert('yes I am click1');
});
$(".click2").click(function() {
  if (confirm('Sure to Click1'))
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='click1 click2'>Click me </span>
```

I tried with the swapping of jquery functions, and it was to call which one is first written, but that will not work in scenario,

There are lots of function written, **now what i want to add a class to element, and want to fire a new permission dialogue, the previous written events will only work if new event allow them to work..

If the question is not clear,

Question is when i say NO to confirmation on **if(confirm('Sure to Click1'))** then click1 should not work.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The last para is my question

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `event.stopImediatePropagation()`. Unfortunately it doesn't play very well with `alert()` and `confirm`.

Comment: Thanks I get it very close, one problem is only how to give priority to first click, ignoring the place of event defination

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p1nmubpw/8/)

Try this one

```
$(".click1").click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass("sure"))
    {
    alert('yes I am click1');
    }
});
$(".click2").click(function () {
    if(confirm('Sure to Click1'))
        {
            $(this).addClass("sure");
        }
    else
    {
            $(this).removeClass("sure");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well, but here it comes:

```js
var allowClick = true;

$(".click1").click(function() {
  if (allowClick === true) {
    alert('yes I am click1');
  }
});
$(".click2").click(function() {
  if (confirm('Sure to Click1')) {
    allowClick = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='click1 click2'>Click me </span>
```

Comment: I cant  unbind any event

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a Boolean variable to the parent scope of both click functions. Then you can set the variable to true or false on the first click, and check if it's been changed on the second click. If you want to slim it down even more, use just one click function with an `if` that checks the condition of that variable. Like so:

```
var isClicked = false;

$(".click").click(function () {
    if (!isClicked) {
        // do first click stuff

        isClicked = true;
    } else {
        // do second click stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This needs to change in each function that is being called

Comment: Ah... Your question changed. Disregard, then.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
$(".one").click(function(){
    alert('one');
});

$(".two").mousedown(function(){
    if(confirm("Sure?"))
        $(".one").trigger("click");
});
```

Mousedown events are fired first and then mouseclick events